# Loop over ID's and add an extra attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an extra attribute depending on a class name but it's not quite working the way I want it.
My menu structure (simplified) is as follows:

```
<ul class="main-menu">

<li>
    <a>Menu 1</a>
    <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
        <div id="km-megamenu-960" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid km-mode-click km-megamenu">dropdown content</div>
    </div>
</li>

<li><a>Menu 2</a></li>

<li>
    <a>Menu 3</a>
    <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
        <div id="km-megamenu-962" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid km-mode-hover km-megamenu">dropdown content</div>
    </div>
</li>

...

</ul>
```

My jquery code is as follows:

```
var ids = $('.km-megamenu').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join(',#');


$('#' + ids).each( function(i) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('km-mode-click') ) {
        $(this).prev(".uk-navbar-dropdown").attr('mode', 'click');
    }

    if ( $(this).hasClass('km-mode-hover') ) {
        $(this).prev(".uk-navbar-dropdown").attr('mode', 'hover');
    }
});
```

Based on the class name `km-mode-hover` or `km-mode-click`, I want to add an extra `attr` inside the `uk-navbar-dropdown` div. E.g:

```
<div class="uk-navbar-dropdown" mode="click">
```

When using `console` all ids are correct. I just have to loop through them correctly. I'm still a newbie when it comes to jquery, 
so if there's anyone who can put me on the right track, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Any reason you are not just looping straight over the classes: `$('.km-megamenu').each(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the way you used the selector.

Instead of mapping and getting each id, i have used a class that the elements you want to iterate have in common.

Then, changed `.prev()` by `.parent()`, since the first should be used to find *siblings* and not *parents*.

```js
$('.km-megamenu').each(function() {
   $parent = $(this).parent('.uk-navbar-dropdown');
   
   if ($(this).hasClass('km-mode-click')) { 
     $parent.attr('mode', 'click');
     console.log('New attribute: ' + $parent.attr('mode'));
   } else if ($(this).hasClass('km-mode-hover')) {
     $parent.attr('mode', 'hover');
     console.log('New attribute: ' + $parent.attr('mode'));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>
    <a>Menu 1</a>
    <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
      <div id="km-megamenu-960" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid km-mode-click km-megamenu">dropdown content</div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><a>Menu 2</a></li>

  <li>
    <a>Menu 3</a>
    <div class="uk-navbar-dropdown">
      <div id="km-megamenu-962" class="uk-navbar-dropdown-grid km-mode-hover km-megamenu">dropdown content</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the element argument passed in by .each() instead of $(this)

```
 var ids = $('.km-megamenu').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get().join(',#');


    $('#' + ids).each( function(index, element) {
        if ( element.hasClass('km-mode-click') ) {
            element.prev(".uk-navbar-dropdown").attr('mode', 'click');
        }

        if ( $(this).hasClass('km-mode-hover') ) {
            element.prev(".uk-navbar-dropdown").attr('mode', 'hover');
        }
    });
```